# JSP/XML : XML parse error - invalid XML

Tags: java, sql, xml, jsp

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.0.39, Eclipse Java EE Juno, Java JRE 7 & Java JDK 1.7.0_13.

I have a problem with the XML, a parse error :

```
Error: Invalid XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <data>
       <time>9</time>
       <instances>3</instances>
   </data>
```

My purpose is to get some information from a database and put them in a Google Chart.
There is my code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%
String idData = request.getParameter("idData");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testcd","root","");

if(conn != null)
{
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("SELECT Id,number FROM numberInstances WHERE ID='"+ idData +"'");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>");
    out.setContentType("text/xml");
    out.println("<data>");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        out.println("<time>" + rs.getString(1) + "</time>");
        out.println("<instances>" + rs.getInt(2) + "</instances>");
    }
    out.println("</data>");

    conn.close();
}
%>
```

Can someone help me? I have this problem since yesterday and all the information I got from my researches on Google didn't help

If you need more information, please ask me

Comment: can you wrap your two tags with the information to a different xml tag and see. So you will not duplicate <time> and <instances> within one <data> tag.

Comment: I will test it but I don't think it's the solution. The syntax works when I did it in PHP. But I need to do it in JSP and something goes wrong. And the database will always return one data!

Comment: you can also try removing this line   out.println("<%@ page contentType=\"text/xml\" " + %&gt;); and just setting the content type on the HttpResponse as out.setContentType("text/xml")

Comment: I tried it but I have the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I changed my code to use text response instead of xml response.
JSP code to get the data :

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("SELECT number FROM numberInstances WHERE ID='"+ idData +"'");
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
while(rs.next())
{
    out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
conn.close();
```

And the JSP code to get the response :

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "resources/jsp/getInstances.jsp",
data: {idData:(cptData)},
dataType: "text",
complete: function(text)
{
    instance = text.responseText*(1010);
}
});
```